# Exposing Dynamics CRM 2011 entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, biztalk, biztalk-2010

How can I expose [Dynamics CRM 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM#Microsoft_Dynamics_CRM_2011) entities like lead, opportunities, etc. to be used in a [EAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration) tool like BizTalk 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that talks about the different approaches that you can use to integrate the two server

> So in real life, your choice as a BizTalk developer will have to be
>   either (a) deal with messiness of creating and consuming untyped
>   messages, or (b) build proxy services for BizTalk to invoke that take
>   in typed objects and communicate to Dynamics CRM.  Ideally the
>   Microsoft team would ship a WCF behavior that I could add to the
>   BizTalk adapter that would do this typed-to-untyped translation both
>   inbound and outbound, but I haven’t heard any mention of anything like
>   that.

[The Good, Bad and Ugly of Integrating Dynamics CRM 2011 and BizTalk Server 2010](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/the-good-bad-and-ugly-of-integrating-dynamics-crm-2011-and-biztalk-server-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Roedl BizTalk Adapter for CRM to do exactly this.  Has saved me a lot of time in mapping untyped repeating nodes back and forth to our defined Entity types.  Functionality is pretty similar to any other WCF-LOB Adapter.

Disclaimer: I don't work for Roedl, but the company I work for is currently looking at a partnering agreement with them.